# onClick Open all Dropdown Menu in table rows

Tags: reactjs

having n number of dropdown menus in React JS. When I am clicking nth menu item, I want to open the corresponding dropdown menu. But what I am getting now is, on clicking a menu item, all the dropdowns are getting opened. How this can be achieved?

Code:-

```
    const [isActive, SetisActive] = useState(false);                           
           {
              PlaylistData && PlaylistData.map((playdata) => {
                                return (
    
      <td >
    
                    <div className="Dropdown">
                <div className="Dropdown_btn" onClick={(e) => SetisActive(!isActive)}>{playdata.ChannelName}</div>
                    {isActive && (
                           Channelname.map((val, id) => {
                                                        {
               return (
                       <Fragment key={id}>
                       {removeRedundant([...val, playdata.ChannelName]).map((val1) => {
                           return (                                                                     
                                    <div className="dropdown_content">                                                                                
   <div className="dropdown_item"                                                                              
          onClick={(e) => { setPlayer(val1, playdata.idx, StoreIdx) }}>{val1}</div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        )
                                                                    })}
                                                                </Fragment>
                                                            )
                                                        }
                                                    })
                                                )}
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting true/false values for your `isActive`, you should set a menu id that you want to open.

I modified your state name from `isActive` to `activeMenu` to align with the value assignment

```
const [activeMenu, setActiveMenu] = useState(); //as no opening menu initially
```

Modify your `onClick` (I don't know your `playdata` has unique id or not so I'm using `ChannelName`. If your data has `id`, you should use it instead)

```
onClick={(e) => setActiveMenu(playdata.ChannelName)}
```

The last part you need to do is just compare your state with the current menu item in the list

```
{activeMenu === playdata.ChannelName && (Channelname.map((val, id) => <elements></elements>)
```

Comment: thanks, it works, please tell me  it's working according to the table row id (open) but when I press it again 2 times it does not close in 1 row, but when I click the 2 rows then 1-row dropdown closed.

Comment: If you want to do that behaviour, you need to modify `onClick` like this `onClick={(e) => activeMenu === playdata.ChannelName ? setActiveMenu(null) : setActiveMenu(playdata.ChannelName)}`. If your active menu is the same as the state, you set value `null` to collapse the menu @ANITAKUMARI